# Setting up MySQL managed by Adminer in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, adminer

I'm just having some trouble setting up Adminer in XAMPP. I'm doing something with databases for the first time, so please bear with me if this is an amateur mistake.

So I dropped the adminer.php file into the htdocs folder of XAMPP and started both Apache and MySQL servers from the XAMPP control panel.
But when I try to log in after going to localhost/adminer.php, I get the error:

```
Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/adminer/discussion/960417/thread/2bf54b69/ Permission of the Account in the mysql

Comment: I think your username or password is wrong. Default parameters of XAMPP are ''root" and "" (empty string). Also I recommend MySQL Workbench for database operations. http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: How do I change it?
Trying to log in by leaving the password field empty gives me 'invalid database'

Answer (score 3):

- Reinstall Xampp
- Run server, go to localhost into phpMyAdmin.php on webpage
- Go to User Accounts and click in last Action "Edit privileges"
- Change password (for example "123456")
- Go to Xampp folder into PhpMyAdmin and open config.inc.php

Replace
 - $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
 - $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

To
 - $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
 - $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123456';

Now

- Donwload Adminer for MySQL and put it in htdocs.
- rename Adminer****.php to Adminer.php
- Open localhost/Adminer.php

Open database

- localhost
- root
- 123456
- *Name of database*